# How do I use React testing library's render method to properly render child components? Currently body tag is coming back empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Currently I am using the shallow method from the enzyme library to write my jest unit test.

```
test("returns component when modal render mode is passed in", () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(
        <MyComponentRenderer appRenderMode={Example.Modal} />
      );

      expect.assertions(2);
      expect(wrapper.getElement()).not.toBeNull();
      expect(wrapper.text()).toBe("<MyComponentRenderer />");
      wrapper.unmount();
    });
```

If I remove the use of the enzyme library, I tried to convert it to the following test

```
test("returns component when modal render mode is passed in", async () => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      render(<MyComponentRenderer appRenderMode={Example.Modal} />);
      screen. debug()
      const MyComponent = await screen.findByTestId(
        "my-component"
      );
      expect(MyComponent).toBeDefined();
    });
```

But the issue is that the screen is coming up empty

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="my-component"]

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>Error: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="my-component"]

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? My actual component that I am testing has nested components, maybe this is why?

Example of my component

```
const ViewComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <DialogComponent customContent={<NewDialog />} /> // imported from another file
);


export const MyComponentRenderer = ({
  appRenderMode,
}: IMyComponentRendererProps) => {
  if (appRenderMode === AppRenderModes.Modal) {
    return <ViewComponent />;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you add the `data-testid` attribute for the component?